# Get KeyPressed when using JCanvas

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a simple Java application using JCanvas, I need to get the key code of a key pressed by the user: The following is a simplified version of the Java Code

```
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
  import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
  import java.util.EventObject;
  import java.awt.event.*;
  // myJavaFiles project contains JCanvas & JEventQueue Classes
  import myJavaFiles.*;
  import javax.swing.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JCanvas canvas = new JCanvas();
    JEventQueue events = new JEventQueue();
    events.listenTo(canvas, "canvas");

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(700, 700);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setFocusable(true);
    frame.add(canvas);

    while (true) {
        if (events.hasEvent()){
            EventObject event = events.waitEvent();
            if(JEventQueue.isKeyPressed(event)){
                int keycode = events.getKeyCode(event);

                // USE KEYCODE!!!

            }
        }
        canvas.sleep(10);
        canvas.clear();
    }
}
```

Everything works, (I omitted a lot of the non relevant code), except for getting the key pressed, I did notice that events.hasEvent doesn't even seem to be true when I press a key!

Please help! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use `while (true)` or `Thread.sleep` this way in Swing applications, unless your goal is to completely lock your application. What is a JCanvas object? Does it extend JPanel?

Comment: It extends JComponent

Comment: Adam: for most key press Swing programs, I would usually favor use of Key Bindings over KeyListeners since that would get rid of the most common focus issues without having to create a kludge, for example a JPanel or JComponent that is required to hold the program's focus at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit difficult without the code for JCanvas and JEventQueue, but normally I would use a key listener for a panel that contains the canvas:

```
//frame.add(canvas);

final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(canvas);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
panel.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        System.out.println("keyEvent.getKeyCode(): " + keyEvent.getKeyCode());
    }
});
```